# Permission denied when installing RVM

Tags: rvm

I'm trying to install rvm. I typed:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=3 --ruby
```

And I got the below

[image: screen shot of result]

Updated:

It's working now. My Xcode was not updated.

But now second problem, also permission denied are the packages. It says it can't be installed. Log is shown below,

```
[2013-05-18 15:37:46] requirements_osx_port_libs_install
--->  Computing dependencies for apple-gcc42
--->  Dependencies to be installed: cctools ld64 llvm-3.2 gcc_select
--->  Building llvm-3.2
Error: org.macports.build for port llvm-3.2 returned: command execution failed
Error: Failed to install llvm-3.2
Please see the log file for port llvm-3.2 for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_llvm-3.2/llvm-3.2/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: cctools ld64 llvm-3.2 gcc_select
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port apple-gcc42 failed
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your `/usr/local` dir is locked to (probably) root. To solve this run this line:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```

It will make it writable for you. That can be an issue but usually it should be not.

Comment: but now I have this when i run it - Error running 'requirements_osx_port_libs_install apple-gcc42 libyaml readline libxml2 libxslt libksba openssl curl-ca-bundle sqlite3 zlib',
please read /Users/ansonzeall/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p195/1368849583_package_install_apple-gcc42_libyaml_readline_libxml2_libxslt_libksba_openssl_curl-ca-bundle_sqlite3_zlib.log

Comment: what does that log file say?